# Javascript using msgreader's attachment Extraction & upload to Azure blob storage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage, msg

I have been using MSG Reader to import emails & extracting attachments into a system with Javascript.

I want to upload that extracted attachments into an azure storage blob.

It uploads, but the file keeps on corrupting.

This is what I have so far:

```
 fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
    var buffer = evt.target.result;
    var msgReader = new MSGReader(buffer);
    var fileData = msgReader.getFileData();
    if (!fileData.error) {
        jQuery.map(fileData.attachments, function (attachment, i) {
            var file = msgReader.getAttachment(i);
            extension = (/[.]/.exec(attachment.fileName)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(attachment.fileName) : '';
            var blobOptions;
            switch(extension[0]) {
                case 'pdf':
                    blobOptions = {blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'application/pdf'}};
                    blobtype = 'application/pdf';
                    break;
                default:
                    blobOptions = {blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'application/octet-stream' }};
                    blobtype = 'application/octet-stream';
            }
            const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, attachment.fileName);
            azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(azblob.Aborter.none, new File([JSON.stringify(file.content)], attachment.fileName, {type:blobtype}), blockBlobURL, blobOptions);
            return;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: so what exceptions did you get?

Comment: None. everything transfered. The files are the exact same size, and everything looks the same. When I want to open the uploaded file, it tells me that the file is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I think that I just used the wrong blob format or something.